# Is it possible to use an IAM Role on an EC2 Instance that uses Ansible Playbooks to affect other instances?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible

I'd like to avoid my AWS instance using Access keys to perform actions via ansible on other AWS Instances. Is there any way to get it to work with a role? It seems like the ansible modules require access keys, but I was uncertain if there is another way.

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/aws/ec2_instance_info_module.html

Comment: It looks like that's built with Boto3, so if you are running this on an EC2 instance, and don't specify any AWS credentials, it should automatically use the EC2 instance's instance profile. Have you tried that? Also that documentation you linked says "Ansible uses the boto configuration file (typically ~/.boto) if no credentials are provided.".

Comment: I have tried that. I receive the error `An error occurred (AuthFailure) when calling the DescribeInstances operation: Authorization header or parameters are not formattted correctly.`

I wasn't able to find the boto config file, but searching right now.

Comment: The boto config file is something you would have to create.

Comment: I see. I was able to get it working without that, I just had to delete my old credentials file. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Mark, I found that this module uses the instance's profile. I fixed the error by deleting my aws credentials file located in ~/.aws/credentials.